# How to get value of input field on focus vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a input field

```
<input @focus="showTimeAvailabilityModal(this)" class="form-control" v-model="date1" placeholder="First Date & Time Preference"/>
```

I called a function showTimeAvailabilityModal on focus of that input field.
I need to get value of input field in this function. How can I do this in simplest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this.

```
showTimeAvailabilityModal(){
var date =this.date1;
}
```

or try this

```
@focus="showTimeAvailabilityModal(date1)"
```